# yii language localization of mysql table data into view

Tags: php, mysql, yii, localization

I have yii language localization turned ON, so I use in config     `'language'=>'en',`
and write things like `Yii::t('layouts_main','Home')` and store translations of `Home` in php file.
But apart of this, I have tables, and there are data inside in different languages.
For example I have a list of countries which must be stored in mysql table in different languages. 
Table structure is very simple: `id, name_en,name_de,name_es` etc...
I did it that way so if language change those 2 letters must be controlling from which sell to read the name.

In my controller I get my data from table to array

```
$tableCountry = Country::model()->findAll();
```

Then I'm making such variable which will containt `"name+"` language variable which is `'en'` in config
`$name_lang ="name_".Yii::app()->Language;`

So now I made variable `$name_lang` which contains `name_en`

Then I choose the right sells using `$name_lang` variable

```
$list=CHtml::listData($modelCountry,'id',$name_lang);
```

Using $name_lang only name_en data will go to List. So later I can switch settings of language in config file to "de" and only name_de data will fgo to List.

So everything is fine here.
But what If I have complex table which contains country_name_en, city_name_en,region_name_en etc...

To put this data into list I have to make 3 or more variables

`$country_name_lang ="country_name_".Yii::app()->Language;`

`$city_name_lang ="city_name_".Yii::app()->Language;`

`$region_name_lang ="region_name_".Yii::app()->Language;`

So I wonder is there any other better way to do such things ?

Comment: if all of your table columns have language suffix, you can put it in default scope of your model

Comment: No unfortunately not all of them have suffix. I mean there are columns like 'id', 'dateCreated' and etc. they have no suffixes. By the way this suffix is also just my thoughts about how to do it, I mean if there is another method maybe it is possible to do it even without? I just don't know how. This is the only method I've came to. It's working , but just thought there will be better way to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Option 1: You can define in the model another variable called country_name (without any suffix). You can do this just in the model, you do not have to create a field in the db too. No need for validation or anything for this variable.
Then in your after find method for the model you can do

```
public function afterFind()
{
    $this->country_name = $this->{"country_name_".Yii::app()->Language};
}
```

Feel free to add everything here.

Now everywhere you should be able to use $model->country_name without any care what the language is.

Option 2 would be to use magic methods. you can read more from them here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php
Define for your model such a method:

```
public function __call($name, $arguments)
{
    if(isset($this->{$name. "_".Yii::app()->Language})) 
        return $this->{$name. "_".Yii::app()->Language}
    elseif(isset($this->$name))
        return $this->{$name}
    else 
        throw new Exception(xxx, 'We couldn\'t find the variable');
}
```

Now you should be able to use $model->country_name() and you would again get the variable in the proper language. You can use also $model->id() and you would get the proper id too as it has a fallback if there is no id_en field.